# how to change url titleLayer mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I need to change my url because I want modify my view map, but I don´t know how I change this url.

I want modify this:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mysaqygi.m8jo7i0g/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```

I use mapbox, but I don´t know how to change this url when I create my map.
where do I change this?

I use leaflet to programming the visualization map

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign to variable like:

```
var url1 = 'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mysaqygi.m8jo7i0g/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer(url1,{});
```

and then

```
tileLayer.setUrl(url2);
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-seturl

You can see [here a demo](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) of leaflet basemaps.

Comment: Yes,but I have a problem with where I obtained this url?? I want change view map, to satellite view, but I don´t know where I create this url

Comment: Do you mean that you want another basemap url and don't know where you can get? See my updated answer.

Comment: I make with your demo but I don´t show nothing.   https://jsfiddle.net/vpjzmrpp/1/

Comment: Oh, with mapbox, you need a key to use it, [it's free](https://www.mapbox.com/account/apps/).

Comment: Always use console to see what is happening.

Comment: But how I use this token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78591/discussion-between-herzo-and-jonatas-walker).